# How to add environment variable to html in nodeJS express app?

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

Say I have an express app:

```
const app = express();

app.use('/sites', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/sites')));
```

And in folder `/sites` there is `index.html`.

The html file contains a form that posts to a server address.
How can I adapt the URL to which the form posts depending on an environment variable?

For example, is it possible to use a placeholder in `index.html` that will be replaced by the NodeJS environment variable before sending it as response to the client?

Comment: Use EJS? or you want it to be without templating engine?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @iRohitBhatia and how would I reference the env variable in the `<%= exampleVar %>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In continuation to my comment, If you don't mind using templating engine, EJS might be a good alternative

I made a [project couple of years back](https://github.com/irohitb/cryptoticker) ,when I was learning programming so don't judge the code but that might help you

Anyway to answer your question from comment,

```
const exampleVar = process.env.exampleVar

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.render("index.ejs", {exampleVar}) 
}
```

Should probably work

Answer (score 2):

You can use express view templating as a solution, check this link [express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html)

Comment: And something more lightweight? Without templating engine?

Comment: unfortunately you can't